# Anylogic does not show me the error on console

Tags: anylogic

I did a model on anylogic. The build does not give me error but when i select "run", the model does nothing and it says "Error" (see image"), nevertheless the console does not show any detail , so i don't know what i did wrong. What could be the mistake?Thanks
the model:https://unisalerno-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/l_aurilio1_studenti_unisa_it/EUGmkBzu9cxLrHtjOzkJu64BgSM6tpZnsEWktP_NgA1d2Q?e=HE3cLj
[image: Error]

Answer (score 1):

the problem was linked with a resource pool,which size was more of 50000, exceeding the maximum value of available agent for student version.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the console DOES show errors. But you can see them in desktop client, not browser:

```
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "AnyLogic model execution control handler"
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Frame Collector"
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "qtp510744362-31"
```

And the reason for those is exceeding of experiment memory. After increasing it from 512Mb to 8Gb it runs.

Comment: Can you tell me the path in order to see this error?

Comment: it does not work after increasing the memory.

Comment: there is no path, look at your Anylogic desktop client as you run your experiment. Console window is popping up there automatically.

Comment: It shows "The model has reached the maximum number of dynamically created agents (50000) for this edition of AnyLogic" but in this case appears when no agent has been created yet. what could be the problem?